# confusion in ecmascript productions

Tags: javascript, ecma262

I've been confused lately about productions in ecma262 spec.

There are productions based on my assumption that can be other productions.

for example, *Statement*

*Statement* can be a *Block* it can also be an *IfStatement*.

my confusion begins with algorithms that looks like that

> a. Let stmtCompletion be the result of evaluating the first **Statement**.

evaluating Statement? What does it mean?

if a *Statement*, for example, is an *IfStatement* will it go to the [14.6 The if Statement 14.6.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
  ?

I'm mostly confused because there are productions that have their **RS: Evaluation** like *IfStatement* and some don't have the **RS: Evaluation** like *Statement*,*Declaration*, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a *Statement*, for example, is an *IfStatement* will it go to the [14.6 The if Statement 14.6.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
> ?

Yes.

> I'm mostly confused because there are productions that have their **RS: Evaluation** like *IfStatement* and some don't have the **RS: Evaluation** like *Statement*,*Declaration*, etc...
>
> What does it mean?

This is (in recent revisions of the spec) even explained in [§5.2.2 Syntax-Directed Operations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions-syntax-directed-operations). In particular,

*Unless explicitly specified otherwise, all chain productions have an implicit definition for every operation that might be applied to that production's left-hand side nonterminal. The implicit definition simply reapplies the same operation with the same parameters, if any, to the chain production's sole right-hand side nonterminal and then returns the result. For example, assume that some algorithm has a step of the form: “Return the result of evaluating `Block`” and that there is a production:*

*`Block : { StatementList }`*

*but the Evaluation operation does not associate an algorithm with that production. In that case, the Evaluation operation implicitly includes an association of the form:*

***Runtime Semantics: Evaluation***

*`Block : { StatementList }`*

1. *Return the result of evaluating `StatementList`.*

So since there are no "Runtime Semantics: Evaluation" for the [`Statement` production](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Statement), it gets implicit semantics that will simply evaluate the respective statement kind.

Comment: "Let stmtCompletion be the result of evaluating the first Statement." it's just an example which i show a scenario where some algorithm use the evaluating Statement which i'm not sure what exactly it does. i took the example from "14.6.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation"

Comment: so that's mean that basically the productions that doesn't have "Runtime Semantics: Evaluation" are referring to the "Runtime Semantics: Evaluation" of their children(can also be their grandchildren) ? in more details, the Statement children are IfStatement,VariableStatement etc... therefore when i encounter an algorithm like "a. Let stmtCompletion be the result of evaluating the first Statement" then it means that it may go to the IfStatement evaluation or it may evaluate a VariableStatement.  but that's depends on the code i wrote. did i understood it correctly ?

Comment: @AngryJohn Yes, exactly that.

Comment: but doesn't it says that a "A chain production is a production that has exactly one nonterminal symbol on its right-hand side along with zero or more terminal symbols." based on my understanding it's says that a production that has exactly one nonterminal along with zero or more terminals on it's right hand side has those implicit "Runtime Semantics: Evaluation" that you indicated. so Statement isn't a chain production ? because it has more than one nonterminal on it's right hand side it has BlockStatement,VariableStatement,EmptyStatement etc... or they meant per alternative ?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the individual [productions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science)). `Statement` is a nonterminal, `Statement → BlockStatement` is the chain production.

Comment: Hey Bergi Just a quick question, in [https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions-syntax-directed-operations](Syntax Directed Operation), at the end of the section it says  "all chain productions have an implicit definition for every operation that might be applied to that production's left-hand side nonterminal." the important part here is the "every operation", that means that every syntax-directed operation whether it's StringValue, BoundsNames, etc.. will have an implicit definition for chain production that doesn't have an algorithm? so it's not only applied on evaluation?

Comment: So, all of them, not just *Evaluation*.